# Avoid django.core.mail.outbox as e-mail backend in test execution on Django

Tags: python, django

In my `settings.py` I have this config about my smtp e-mail backend:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.zoho.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user@domain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'user'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'contact@domain.com'
```

When I run the server during development (i.e. `python manage.py runserver`), e-mails are sent normally. But when I run my acceptance tests (i.e. `python manage.py test functional_tests`), e-mails are not sent.

Reading the docs, I found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#email-services) that Django assumes that is a good thing to send e-mails for a dummy box during testing, but the docs does not tell how I can disable this functionality (I do want to send e-mails via smtp while runing tests).

Someone knows what I have to do to send e-mails via smtp when running tests?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: mock the method perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`override_settings`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings) decorator.

```
from django.test import override_settings

class TestView(TestCase):
    @override_settings(EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend')
    def test_view(self):
       ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using [StaticLiveServerTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#specialized-test-case-to-support-live-testing) and, when I use `@override_settings`, test execution throws an error: `NameError: name 'overrride_settings' is not defined`. I have used `from django.test import override_settings`. I also saw that `StaticLiveServerTestCase` is a subclass of `TestCase`, so I'm not getting why this is happening. Of course, I'm very new in Django development. :)

Comment: You copied my typo. There are only two `r`s in override.